# Formatting JSON response in Laravel 5 for Select2.js

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, jquery-select2

I am populating a city list (after selecting a county from a dropdown), using an Ajax call with Laravel 5.2 and Select2.js.

I want to format the JSON response from the ajax call so it matches the Select2 criterias for displaying on a dropdown list (`id`,`text`)

Here is my controller:

```
public function postCounty(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()) 
    {
        $county = County::findOrFail($request->input('county_id'));
        $cities = $county->cities()->orderBy('title', 'ASC')->get();
        return response()->json($cities);
    }
}
```

It works fine and return a list of cities:

```
[
    {"id":1,"title":"City 1","slug":"city-1"},
    {"id":2,"title":"City 2","slug":"city-2"},
    {"id":3,"title":"City 3","slug":"city-3"}
]
```

I need to retrieve only the columns `id` and `title`, so I use `->pluck('title', 'id')`

It returns this:

```
{"1":"City 1","2":"City 2","3":"City 3"}
```

To display the results correctly on my select options list, using Select2, I need the results to return like this:

```
[
    {"id":"1","text":"City 1"},
    {"id":"2","text":"City 2"},
    {"id":"3","text":"City 3"}
]
```

I know that I can format the results from the `->get()` array, using JavaScript and the Select2 `processResults`, but I want to do it using the controller so it formats the JSON response directly.

Here is a simplified version of my JS:

```
$("#countyFilter").select2().on("select2:selecting", function(e) {
    var county_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'mysite.com/api/county',
        data: {county_id:county_id},
        success: function(data){
            $("#populateCities").select2({
                data:data
            });
        }
    });
});
```

That script works almost fine, only the `data` needs to be formatted.

**My question:**

How to format the JSON response in the controller so it returns `[{"id":1,"text":"City 1"}]` instead of `[{"id":1,"title":"City 1","slug":"city-1"}]`

Comment: BTW `formatting` means something different from what you think.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Does it only mean "deleting" like in "formatting a hard disk"? I should have use "output" maybe. My english is not on point yet :)

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `select('id','title')`

```
    $county = County::findOrFail($request->input('county_id'));
    $cities = $county->cities()->select('id','title')->orderBy('title', 'ASC')->get();
    return response()->json($cities);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Now is there a way to change `title` to `text`? (that was in my question too)

Comment: Change `select('id','title')` to `select('id','title as text')`